# MongoDB: As the number of fields to group by in $group increases will there be any performance impact?

Tags: mongodb

I am looking for ways to improve my aggregation queries. In that context, I was wondering if the number of fields that get grouped impacts the performance of the aggregation? Because in certain cases we group by more than 5 to 6 fields.

In other words, as the number of fields to group by in `$group` pipeline increases will there be any performance impact compared to let's say when grouped by 1 or 2 fields?

**More details**:
If the answer to this is yes, it could negatively impact performance, then I plan to create a new field let's call it "cocatenated_field" inside which I will string concatenate values of all the multiple fields and then use only this one field for grouping.

Comment: Interesting question. Grouping should be defined by application logic, I can't think about any scenario where you have flexibility to change grouping for the sake of optimisation alone. Just out of curiosity, could you provide some details?

Comment: Added "More Details" to the question. Does that make sense? Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: difference shall be relatively small to none in case there is no other stages in the pipeline.

Comment: There would be other stages including calculations (such as count, sum, multiplication, division, etc. within grouping), $facet, $sort, etc.

Comment: Also, does compression (storage.wiredTiger.collectionConfig.blockCompressor) impact performance? Such that if I turn off the compression will the performance improve? 

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#mongodb-setting-storage.wiredTiger.collectionConfig.blockCompressor

Comment: $group is a blocking stage, means the aggregation will stop at this stage until all documents are processed. Indexes matter much more then number of fields. As long as all fields are in a prefix of a compound index, it will be optimal.